# joomla json like string... what is it? smarty? joomla core?

Tags: php, joomla

Someone asked me to connect to a remote database which is based on joomla with some components on it.
On of which has a database field called "ad_features" which contains json-ish like info like:

```
a:10:{i:0;s:2:"76";i:1;s:2:"77";i:2;s:2:"82";i:3;s:2:"83";i:4;s:2:"87";i:5;s:2:"89";i:6;s:2:"92";i:7;s:2:"93";i:8;s:2:"94";i:9;s:1:"0";}
```

I've been wading through the joomla code, but I cant seem to find the function which relates to the decoding of this string. Is this a function from joomla itself or smarty? or something else?

If now, does anyone know what this is at all and how to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generated by [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

You can [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it.

Example:

```
$array=unserialize('a:10:{i:0;s:2:"76";i:1;s:2:"77";i:2;s:2:"82";i:3;s:2:"83";i:4;s:2:"87";i:5;s:2:"89";i:6;s:2:"92";i:7;s:2:"93";i:8;s:2:"94";i:9;s:1:"0";}');
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 76 [1] => 77 [2] => 82 [3] => 83 [4] => 87 [5] => 89 [6] => 92 [7] => 93 [8] => 94 [9] => 0 )
```